# PHPUNIT Mocking method to accept any parameter

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I use [simple-phpunit from phpunit/phpunit-bridge](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html) by and with Symfony here.

I have a class A, that I desire to test, which uses a class B method in it.

While mocking the B and it's method I realise it is called multiple time and with multiple parameters : a class name and a integer.
I use returnValueMap() for this but have a problem : PHPUNIT seem to require that I precisely set the parameters, to their exact value when the method shall be called.
I can set the class name ( there are a given possible number fo them , so I can set them manually) but the given integer is arbitrary ( and the method is called in a loop ) , therefore I cannot set it precisely.

Is it possible to tell PHPUNIT to accept any parameter to this function ?
Like a anyParameter() method ( that I did not find after scouring the TestCase file ).

If I set the Integer parameter to a fixed value in the test and the class method, the test pass ( but of course I can't set the Integer as a fixed value in the class method ).

```
class ToBeTested{
     public $objectB;
     public function functionToTest($dataList){
        ......
        $objectB=new ObjectB();
        foreach($dataList as $data){
            $className=$data['className'];
            $integerNeeded=$data['integer'];
            //Here if $inetegerNeeded is not the exact value set in the Mock
            //$result will be null
            $result=$this->objectB->doSomething($className,$integerNeeded);
            if($result == null) throw new \Excpetion(" Object is null");
        }
        .....
     }
}
```

---

```
class UnitTest extends TestCase{
       /**
         $generatedDataList comes from a DataProvider 
          with some varied and exotic data close to real use cases
       **/
       public function testFunction($generatedDataList)
       {
           $mockOfObjectB= $this->getMockBuilder(ObjectB::class)
                 ->getMock();
          /**
      Here I'd like to use $this->anyParameter() or something that'd work that      way 
      If I set this to a fixed value here and in the functionToTest() method it   passes 
          **/
           $anyInteger=-1;  
           $dataReferenceMap= [
              ['ClassNameA',$anyInteger,new MockObject()],
              ['ClassNameB',$anyInteger,new MockObject()],
              ['ClassNameC',$anyInteger,new MockObject()],
           ];
           $mockOfObjectB
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('doSomething')
            ->will($this->returnValueMap($dataReferenceMap));
            $objectToTest = new ToBeTested();
            $objectToTest->objectB=$mockOfObjectB;

            //DO THE TESTING - will because of the parameter Fail 
            $objectToTest->functionToTest($generatedDataList);
          }
    }
}
```

Might I also be wrongly [`returnValueMap()`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-stubs-examples-stubtest5-php) ?

It's quite new to me and I think the docs on it are pretty scarce and don't explain really well how to use it.

Comment: Tip: If you find the docs leaving open too many questions (can be the case with other docs as well), create some tests just to test-run and play with these mocking apart from the test-case you currently write. That often helps me to actually learn about the mocking framework, can try-out while reading docs (or blog posts) and check if I got it right. Then I apply it to the real test I'm working on and it's all fine and dandy (and yes, playing includes asking on SO, but there is much power by isolating an issue and solve it isolated. The take-away often is much greater as expected).

Comment: According to your question you can make the method *always* return the `new MockObject()`,  I don't see any need to use the return-value-map.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `willReturnCallback`. Here is the example (checked with phpunit 8.1)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSome()
    {
        $mock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(\stdClass::class)
            ->setMethods(['doSomething'])
            ->getMock();
        $mock->method('doSomething')
            ->willReturnCallback(
                function (string $classname, int $int) {
                    $map = [
                    'ClassNameA' => 123,
                    'ClassNameB' => 345,
                    // ...
                    ];
                    return $map[$classname];
                }
            );
        $this->assertSame(123, $mock->doSomething('ClassNameA', 1));
        $this->assertSame(123, $mock->doSomething('ClassNameA', 1111111));
        $this->assertSame(345, $mock->doSomething('ClassNameB', 13456));
        $this->assertSame(345, $mock->doSomething('ClassNameB', 999999));
    }
}
```

It is a shortcut for `->will($this->returnCallback(...))`. [The doc](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/test-doubles.html#test-doubles-stubs-examples-stubtest6-php)